# Print sums of each column & sums of each row of Matrix in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stuck on how to find the sums of each column & row of Matrix in Java. I don't know how to find the result of column and row separately. Thank you in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double [][] a = new double [2][3]; 
        a[0][0] = 1;
        a[0][1] = 2;
        a[0][2] = 3;
        a[1][0] = 4;
        a[1][1] = 5;
        a[1][2] = 6; 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            String str = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                str += a[i][j] + "\t"; 
            }
            System.out.println(str); 
        }

        // column sums
        double[] b = new double[a[0].length]; 


       // row sums
```

Comment: To find the sum of a column : Iterate through each column, initialize a sum variable, increment through each row of that column and add the value to the sum.

Comment: it is not clear, please add more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Use two nested loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < a.length(); j++) {
        b[i] += a[j][i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the sum of a one-dimensional segment of a n-dimensional array, you will need to form a nested loop to iterate through n-dimensional array, with a loop for each dimension. At the deepest step of each iteration, once you are inside the inner-most nested loop, you can increment the total value by the value referenced at that particular point in iteration.

```
    double[][] a = new double[2][3];
    a[0][0] = 1;
    a[0][1] = 2;
    a[0][2] = 3;
    a[1][0] = 4;
    a[1][1] = 5;
    a[1][2] = 6;

    for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(a[row][col] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    double[] rowTotals = new double[a.length];
    double[] colTotals = new double[a[0].length];

    for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
            rowTotals[row] += a[row][col];
            colTotals[col] += a[row][col];
        }
    }
```

I notice in your question you wanted to find the row and column totals separately. If this is a must (I can't see why), you can simply duplicate the nested loop and dedicate one loop for column totals and one for row totals.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Considering 
    // row1: 123
    // row2: 456

    List<Double> colsSum = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(a[0].length, 0.0));
    List<Double> rowsSum = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        double row = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
            row += a[i][j];
            colsSum.set(j, colsSum.get(j) == 0 ? a[i][j]
                : colsSum.get(j) + a[i][j]);
        }
        rowsSum.add(row);
    }
```